# Write the problem as a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

In tower block can be three types of floors: floors which has

**a)** $3$ three-room, $7$ two-room and $8$ one-room apartment

**b)** $4$ three-room, $4$ two-room and $8$ one-room apartment   or

**c)** $5$ three-room, $3$ two-room and $9$ one-room apartment

Is it possible to build tower block, which has $66$ three-room, $74$ two-room and $136$ one-room apartment?
If it is, is there several options to do that, and how many floors the tower block has?

Write the problem as a linear system of equations, and explain what the symbols mean, and solve equations by using Gauss method.

I know how to solve equations by using Gauss method, but I don't know how to write that problem as a linear system of equations?

**I tried this:**

$\begin{cases}
3x+7y+8z=1
\\
4x+4y+8z=2
\\
5x+3y+9z=3
\end{cases}$

and

$66x+74y+136z=a$

But obviously it is not correct linear system of equations.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

As @Yunus Syed suggested I used:

$\begin{cases}
3x+4y+5z=66
\\
7x+4y+3z=74
\\
8x+8y+9z=136
\end{cases}$

and when I used Gauss elimination method I got this:

$\begin{cases}
x=2+\frac{1}{2}z
\\
y=15-\frac{13}{8}z
\\
z\quad is free
\end{cases}$

When I choosed $z=8$ then I got:

$\begin{cases}
x=6
\\
y=2
\\
z=8
\end{cases}$

So it possible to build tower block, which has $66$ three-room, $74$ two-room and $136$ one-room apartment (?)

And as answer to "If it is, is there several options to do that" is it simply yes because $z$ is free, so I can get any $x, y, z$ values ?

Also does e.g. $x$ value means how many floors is in block a?
From which I get answer to "how many floors the tower block has" by just summing up blocks and getting $x+y+z=6+2+8=16$ floors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $x$ of block a, $y$ of block b, and $z$ of block c. Then we have to satisfy the criterion and the only system that does so is:

\begin{cases}
3x+4y+5z=66
\\
7x+4y+3z=74
\\
8x+8y+9z=136
\end{cases}

To answer your follow up questions: Yes, Yes, and Yes. One thing to be careful about is the number of possibilities to have an ordered pair $(x, y, z)$. Luckily, there are two $z$ values which give you non-negative values for $x,y$; 0 and 8.

Comment: Thanks :) But what do I do when I get a, b, c values?

Comment: Then you found a way to construct your tower :)

Comment: Yunus Syed check out my original question the "update" section

Comment: Yes, Yes, and Yes

Comment: Okey, thanks for your help :)

Comment: But about the number of possibilities, do I need to specify the amount of possiblities, or is it enough the answer to be "There is several options, because $z$ is free. But only with such a value of $z\in\mathbb{N}$ whereby $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: Yes (15 characters)

Comment: How do you calculate that there is 15 characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55276/discussion-between-yunus-syed-and-redrose).